# Pagespeed + yandex metrika + google analytics = bad speed

Tags: google-analytics, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, yandex-metrika

I need help to optimize my website ggsel.com. I use counters of google analytics and  Yandex Metrica. If I drop these counters then I get very good results by page speed, but if I put these counters in my page result is bad.

I attached screenshots from page speed to this post. Please tell me, how to save these counters and getting the best result from page speed. And maybe can you give me some advice for me. How I can better FID and FCP for my site?

[with metrica and analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjMzz.jpg)

[without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI2hc.jpg)